# How to graph different variables with different length in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter, variable-length

I have 165545*1 double and 1*351 double variables. I want to put 165545 * 1 on y axis and 1*351 on x axis using plot(x,y) or scatter(x,y).

Comment: Every point in 2D include (x,y).

Comment: Every point from 1*351 maybe include many points from 165545*1

Comment: Do you have a func(x, y) that you want to plot against? Cause right now it makes no sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to plot two variables with different size length on matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645185/how-to-plot-two-variables-with-different-size-length-on-matlab)

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions. If you are not getting relevant answers to your question, clarify your question and respond to the suggestions given to you in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can select random x' to build xi vector with same number of elements as y:

```
idx=randi([1,length(x)],1,length(y));
xi=x(idx);
scatter(xi,y)
```